# how to write hasMany tables in MappingClass of Fluent Nhibernate configuration of NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm new in NHibernate . I have three tables one is user and two other brand and group
user connected with brand oneToMany
user connected with group oneToMany
I'm using FluentNhibernate mapping to map all data but I'm stuck with here
how to map two classes HasMany part . I can't write down two HasMany into this but I either can't  write down in one's HasMany part.How I can realize it please suggest to me ?

```
public UserMap() 
        {
            Id(x => x.id);
            Map(x => x.username);
            Map(x => x.password);
            Map(x => x.deleted);
            Map(x => x.role);
            Map(x => x.create_date);
            HasMany(x => x.brand).KeyColumn("user_id").Inverse().Cascade.All();
            //this second dosn't work
HasMany(x => x.group).KeyColumns("user_id").Inverse().Cascade.All();


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Scince your `User` has `one-to-many` relations with `Brand` and `Group`. Your `User` class would have two collections: 
`Brands` and `Groups`. You would map it like this:

```
public UserMap() 
...
HasMany(x => x.Brands).KeyColumn("user_id").Cascade.All().Inverse();
HasMany(x => x.Groups).KeyColumn("user_id").Cascade.All().Inverse();
```

then:

```
public BrandMap() 
...
References(x => x.User).Column("user_id").Not.Nullable();
```

and:

```
public GroupMap() 
...
References(x => x.User).Column("user_id").Not.Nullable();
```